# Error: Cannot find module 'openai' in Svelte application

Tags: node.js, npm, svelte, openai-api

Description of the Problem:
I'm encountering an issue in my Svelte application where I'm getting the following error message:

`Error: Cannot find module 'openai' or its corresponding type declarations.js(2307)`

**Relevant Code:**
Here's the relevant part of my code where I'm importing and using the openai module:

```
import OpenAI from "openai";
const openai = new OpenAI();

async function apiFetch() {
  // ... 
}
```

**Package.json:**
Here are the relevant parts of my package.json to show the dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "dapp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "openai": "^4.19.1",
    // ... other dependencies
  },
  // ... other configurations
}
```

**Installation Steps:**

I installed the openai package using the following steps:

- Ran npm install openai
- Checked node_modules to ensure the openai folder is present

**Other Attempts:**
I've checked for any typos in the import statement and restarted the development server.

I didn't try anything in particular because that's all I know, I was expecting it to work, but it didn't

Comment: When do you get this error? During build? Or is it shown in the IDE you use?

Comment: it's shown in the IDE, it underlines the word "openai" with a red squiggly line

Comment: Does the code build? If not, please show what error messages you get.